# Calculo automático em caixa de texto

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Bom dia. Existe alguma forma de quando o usuário digitar isso em uma caixa de texto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um script executar a conta automaticamente e resultar, neste caso, =1 ?
É importante também que ele faça isso com todas as operações e que seja em javascript puro.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim isso é possivel. A maneira mais fácil é usando o `eval();`.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="calculator" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('calculator');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
input.addEventListener('keyup', calcular);
function calcular(){
    var conta = eval(this.value);
    result.innerHTML = conta;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/4djdy/1

O exemplo em cima agarra um oscultador de evento `keyup` e corre uma função cada vez que uma tecla fôr libertada (keyup). 
Essa função corre o `eval()` que no fundo corre essa string como código.

Existem outras maneiras mais seguras e trabalhosas, isso implica regex para detetar operadores como divisão, multiplicação, etc. Mas penso que este exemplo responde ao que pergunta.

---

## Sem `eval()`:

Tenho de deixar um parentesis: o eval() é uma das ferramentas mais poderosas do JavaScript é pode ser muito util, mas em alguns casos levanta problemas de segurança.
<sub>(Mais sobre isso [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27688/129))</sub>

Se quiser fazer o mesmo sem o eval, o código fica bem mais extenso. Por curiosidade fiz à mão um código para resolver isto. Talvez dê para economizar algumas linhas mas não será muito mais pequeno sem o uso do eval(). Porem este exemplo (http://jsfiddle.net/n34PT/) é eval-free:

```
var input = document.getElementById('calculator');
input.addEventListener('keyup', calcular);

function calcular(e) {
    calculadora(e.target.value);
}
var conta = 0;
var operadores = ['*', '/', '+', '-', ];
var operacoes = [

function (a, b) {
    return a * b;
},

function (a, b) {
    return a / b;
},

function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
},

function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
}];
var stop = 0;

function resolverParentesis(eq) {
    return eq.replace(/\(.*\)/, function (match) {
        return calculadora(match.substring(1, match.length - 1));
    });
}

function calculadora(pedido) {
    if (pedido.match(/[*\/+\-]$/)) return;
    var pedido = pedido.replace(/\s/g, '');
    pedido = resolverParentesis(pedido);
    if (!/[*\/+\-]/.test(pedido)) return resultado(pedido);
    var regex = /[*\/]/.test(pedido) ? new RegExp("([^\/*+\-]*[*\/][^\/*+\-]*)") : new RegExp("([^\/*+\-]*[+\-][^\/*+\-]*)");
    pedido = processar(pedido, regex);
    if (/[*\/+\-]/.test(pedido)) return calculadora(pedido);
    return resultado(pedido);
}

function processar(input, regex) {
    return input.replace(regex, function (str) {
        var op = str.match(/([*\/+\-])/)[0];
        var pedacos = str.split(op);
        var fn = operacoes[operadores.indexOf(op)];
        return fn(pedacos[0] * 1, pedacos[1] * 1);
    });
}

function resultado(conta){
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = conta
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do sérgio usando eval é uma solução simples mas ela tem alguns problemas:

- Segurança: o eval vai executar qualquer código Javascript, não só as expressões aritméticas. Você tem que tomar cuidado para que apenas valores escritos pelo próprio usuário sejam avaliados, para evitar vulnerabilidades de [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).
- O eval é uma caixa preta: ou ele retorna o resultado da conta ou nada. Em particular:

  - Você não tem controle sobre como as mensagens de erro são geradas.
  - Você não tem controle sobre como as contas são feitas e não pode definir os seus próprios operadores.

Se essas limitações forem importantes, uma alternativa é fazer as contas você mesmo. Construa um parser que converta o texto em uma árvore de sintaxe e avalie essa árvore. É um pouco comprido demais para descrever num post do SO, mas você encontra como fazer isso em diversos livros de algoritmos e pela internet (eu recomendaria um parser top-down - é mais fácil de programar na mão e as mensagens de erro são mais simples)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318667/Mathematical-Expression-Parser-Using-Recursive-Des

Comment: Sobre a árvore de sintaxe, [essa outra questão aqui do SOPT](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23464/arvore-gen%C3%A9rica-como-fazer) tem algumas informações que podem ser úteis. Não usa a mesma linguagem, mas a leitura da pergunta e da resposta podem fornecer algumas *intuições* importantes sobre a solução alternativa que o @hugomg sugeriu. :)

Comment: Hugo, o eval pode ser muito útil como no caso desta pergunta. Mas para completar a [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27608/129) juntei uma versão sem eval.

Comment: No caso de criar um parser como sugerido aqui nesta resposta, vale uma olhada nas seguintes ferramentas: [jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/), [esprima](http://esprima.org/) e [peg](http://pegjs.majda.cz/).

Answer (score 0):

Baseada na [resposta do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27608/23192), criei um exemplo mais simples sem o uso do `eval()`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('calculator');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
input.addEventListener('keyup', calcular);
function calcular(){
    //var conta = eval(this.value);
    var conta = new Function("return " + this.value);
    var resultado = conta();
    
    result.innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="calculator" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Neste caso uma [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) é criada com base na string enviada.
Perceba que alguns erros aparecerão no console em alguns momentos, pois o tipo de retorno "1+1+", por exemplo, não é válido.

Neste caso, você poderia resolver com uma simples validação antes de criar a função. Isso resolveria o problema de "caixa preta" [citado pelo hugomg em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27611/23192). Mas ainda assim teríamos o problema do XSS.

Essa resposta tem apenas como finalidade somar conhecimento das diversas possibilidades possíveis de resolver seu problema de forma simples.

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4903/23192) você pode encontrar muitos outros exemplos.